# Does thread_local work for OpenMP threads?

Tags: c++, openmp, thread-local-storage

If I use `thread_local int x = 0`, will each OpenMP thread see its own instance of `x`? Since search for `thread_local` in https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5.0.pdf doesn't find anything I guess not, but would be happy to hear otherwise.

If it isn't guaranteed, can it be combined with `threadprivate` as

```
thread_local int x = 0;
#pragma omp threadprivate(x)
```

Or do I need something like

```
#ifdef USE_OPENMP
int x = 0;
#pragma omp threadprivate(x)
#else
thread_local int x = 0;
#endif
```

instead?

EDIT: High Performance Mark gave a link to the 5.1 draft in the comments, which says

> Variables that appear in `threadprivate` directives or variables with the `_Thread_local` (in C) or `thread_local` (in C++) storage-class specifier are threadprivate

Comment: no answer will ever be as good as just checking

Comment: Note "guaranteed". If something works on my machine, for a specific compiler version, etc, doesn't mean it does in general.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Great, thank you!